# MongoDB C driver efficiency

Tags: c++, linux, mongodb

I'm trying to write a program whose job it is to go into shared memory, retrieve a piece of information (a `struct` 56 bytes in size), then parse that struct lightly and write it to a database.

The catch is that it needs to do this several dozens of thousands of times per second. I'm running this on a dedicated Ubuntu 14.04 server with dual Xeon X5677's and 32GB RAM. Also, Mongo is running PerconaFT as its storage engine. I am making an uneducated guess here, but say worst case load scenario would be 100,000 writes per second.

Shared memory is populated by another program who's reading information from a real time data stream, so I can't necessarily reproduce scenarios.

First... is Mongo the right choice for this task?

Next, this is the code that I've got right now. It starts with creating a list of collections (the list of items I want to record data points on is fixed) and then retrieving data from shared memory until it catches a signal.

```
int main()
{
  //these deal with navigating shared memory
  uint latestNotice=0, latestTurn=0, latestPQ=0, latestPQturn=0;
  symbol_data *notice = nullptr;
  bool done = false;

  //this is our 56 byte struct
  pq item;

  uint64_t today_at_midnight; //since epoch, in milliseconds
  {
    time_t seconds = time(NULL);
    today_at_midnight = seconds/(60*60*24);
    today_at_midnight *= (60*60*24*1000);
  }

  //connect to shared memory
  infob=info_block_init();
  uint32_t used_symbols = infob->used_symbols;
  getPosition(latestNotice, latestTurn);

  //fire up mongo
  mongoc_client_t *client = nullptr;
  mongoc_collection_t *collections[used_symbols];
  mongoc_collection_t *collection = nullptr;
  bson_error_t error;
  bson_t *doc = nullptr;

  mongoc_init();
  client = mongoc_client_new("mongodb://localhost:27017/");

  for(uint32_t symbol = 0; symbol < used_symbols; symbol++)
  {
    collections[symbol] = mongoc_client_get_collection(client, "scribe",
                                         (infob->sd+symbol)->getSymbol());
  }

  //this will be used later to sleep one millisecond
  struct timespec ts;
  ts.tv_sec=0;
  ts.tv_nsec=1000000;

  while(continue_running) //becomes false if a signal is caught
  {
    //check that new info is available in shared memory
    //sleep 1ms if it isn't
    while(!getNextNotice(&notice,latestNotice,latestTurn)) nanosleep(&ts, NULL);

    //get the new info
    done=notice->getNextItem(item, latestPQ, latestPQturn);
    if(done) continue;

    //just some simple array math to make sure we're on the right collection
    collection = collections[notice - infob->sd];

    //switch on the item type and parse it accordingly
    switch(item.tp)
    {
      case pq::pq_event:
        doc = BCON_NEW(
                       //decided to use this instead of std::chrono
                       "ts", BCON_DATE_TIME(today_at_midnight + item.ts),
                       //item.pr is a uint64_t, and the guidance I've read on mongo
                       //advises using strings for those values
                       "pr", BCON_UTF8(std::to_string(item.pr).c_str()),
                       "sz", BCON_INT32(item.sz),
                       "vn", BCON_UTF8(venue_labels[item.vn]),
                       "tp", BCON_UTF8("e")
                      );
        if(!mongoc_collection_insert(collection, MONGOC_INSERT_NONE, doc, NULL, &error))
        {
          LOG(1,"Mongo Error: "<<error.message<<endl);
        }
        break;
      //obviously, several other cases go here, but they all look the
      //same, using BCON macros for their data.
      default:
        LOG(1,"got unknown type = "<<item.tp<<endl);
        break;
    }
  }

  //clean up once we break from the while()
  if(doc != nullptr) bson_destroy(doc);

  for(uint32_t symbol = 0; symbol < used_symbols; symbol++)
  {
    collection = collections[symbol];
    mongoc_collection_destroy(collection);
  }

  if(client != nullptr) mongoc_client_destroy(client);
  mongoc_cleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

My second question is: is this the fastest way to do this? The retrieval from shared memory isn't perfect, but this program is getting way behind its supply of data, far moreso than I need it to be. So I'm looking for obvious mistakes with regards to efficiency or technique when speed is the goal.

Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: Sleeping is never a good way to get best performance.  56 bytes * 100,000 writes per second is 5.6 MB/s.  One disk can do that if you treat it right (few seeks).  If MongoDB will treat the disk right, you would need to test.  When you profile the code, where is the time spent?

Comment: `opreport` says 18% of time is spent getting data items, while 10% is spent in libstdc++ (no location information) and 2% is spent in libc's fwrite. I guess that vindicates Mongo and the rest, doesn't it? Looks like this mechanism for distributing information needs retooling.